# How to create PL/pgSQL function returning several rows

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, return-type, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to create [a PL/pgSQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql.html), which should populate a temporary table and then return all rows from it (it will be a join later), but I don't know which return type to specify for it:

```
create or replace function pref_daily_misere() returns void as $BODY$
        begin

        create temporary table temp_best (id varchar not null) on commit drop;
        insert into temp_best (id) select id from pref_money where
            yw = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
            order by money desc limit 10;
        select id from temp_best;
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

The statements above work on their own, but give me the error

```
# select pref_daily_misere();
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "pref_daily_misere" line 7 at SQL statement
```

when I try to call it in my PostgreSQL 8.4.11 database.

This is probably because I have wrongly specified the **returns void** above, but I don't know which return type to use instead and omitting the return type is a compile error.

Comment: Is there any reason to tuck the above stuff insde a function? A view (or CTE) seems perfectly suited, IMHO. (maybe except for the ugly limit)

Comment: It is not a complete function, I'll add more stuff later there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a `setof varchar` return type and then `return query ...` inside the function. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54103):

> **39.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY**
>
> ```
> RETURN NEXT expression;
> RETURN QUERY query;
> RETURN QUERY EXECUTE command-string [ USING expression [, ... ] ];
> ```
>
> When a PL/pgSQL function is declared to return `SETOF` ***sometype***, the procedure to follow is slightly different. In that case, the individual items to return are specified by a sequence of `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` commands, and then a final `RETURN` command with no argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing.

I think you want something more like this:

```
create or replace function pref_daily_misere() returns setof varchar as $BODY$
begin
    create temporary table temp_best (id varchar not null) on commit drop;
    insert into temp_best (id)
    select id
    from pref_money
    where yw = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
    order by money
    desc limit 10;
    return query select id from temp_best;
    return;
end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

However, the temp table is pointless here:

> **Note:** The current implementation of `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` stores the entire result set before returning from the function, as discussed above.

So PostgreSQL is computing the entire result set and caching it by itself. You could do this:

```
create or replace function pref_daily_misere() returns setof varchar as $BODY$
begin
    return query
        select id
        from pref_money
        where yw = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
        order by money
        desc limit 10;
    return;
end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

I'm pretty sure the temp table is going to be dropped at the end of your function anyway so you should get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you, but why is the second `return` necessary? I've commented it out and it seems to work ok.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: The second `return;` isn't necessary but the docs say "a final `RETURN` command with no argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing" so I put it in to avoid questions about why it wasn't there :)